# Where is JavaScript's localstorage strings stored?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, firefox

Where is `localstorage` strings stored on the operating system? Is it in Firefox's Profile folder?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In firefox it's in the webappsstore.sqlite file in the profile folder.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data

Answer (score 1):

> The DOM storage data is stored in the webappsstore.sqlite file in the
>   profile folder.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Webappsstore.sqlite

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder