# HTML5 local storage physical location in android

Tags: cordova

I am wondering where is physical location of localstorage in android mobile.

I am implementing HTML5 Hybrid app using phonegap.

can anybody tell me where android app stores its localstorage values(i.eIn SD card or In the app itself)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is JavaScript's localstorage strings stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775844/where-is-javascripts-localstorage-strings-stored)

Comment: Could you find it? I'm facing the same issue.