# How to save data in local hd with javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, navigator

I'm using CKEditor to create text in a website that create documents. The problem is the internet connection, the PC is far away from town and it's unstable 3G connection. I already have a routine to save a draft every ten seconds (or the time the user wish to be) in the server for safe - simple task. The problem is that if the internet goes down, the user will have to select - copy the text and try to save it locally with some text editor (maybe Word, that will make a mess).

So I'm wondering if already exists a way of to create a file and download to the local HD without remote server, just the JavaScript and navigator. Also, it might be another way to save the job but keeping CPU on and navigator open, but couldn't find in stack overflow.

I found just one non-standard API FireFox compatible: 
[Device Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Device_Storage_API)
Of course, is not JavaScript standard so I don't know if it's a good idea to use right now.

Any ideas?

Comment: [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) or create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)

Comment: Offering a download link (e.g. with a blob URL) that will let the user save a file seems good, except that it will need user interaction every time you want to save or load. Local storage will save a limited amount of data in the browser (hopefully enough for you) without interaction.

Comment: You also have the option of indexedDB if a pure browser solution is fine

Comment: In fact, I wish the interaction (download box) because will alert the user that the connection is down, so he know will have to save the work in HD to restart later, by an upload of the saved work. So if I do create a blob, how do I launch a download box? There is no blob.download method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Compatibility Note]

> This solution uses `<a>` attribute **`download`**, to save the data in a text file.
>   This html5 attribute is only  supported by  [Chrome 14+, Firefox 20+ and Opera
>   15+](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html) on
>   *desktop*, none on *iOS* and all current majors except WebView on *Android*.
>
> -A workaround for IE 10+ is to not hide/destroy the link generated by `clickSave()`and ask user to `right-click` > `Save target As…`
>
> -No known workaround for Safari.
>
> Also note that data will still be accessible via
>   [localStorage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)
>   for Firefox 3.5+, Chrome&Safari 4+, Opera 10.5+ and IE 9+ *(xhr will
>   crash IE 8-)*

---

I would do it like so, assuming your actual code saves the data via [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

```js
function saveData() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //set a timeout, in ms, to see if we're still connected
    xhr.timeout = 2000;
    xhr.addEventListener('timeout', localStore, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        // not a good news
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
          localStore();
        }
        else{
          document.querySelector('#local_alert').style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
    //I assume you already have the part where you set the credentials
    xhr.open('POST', 'your/url.php');
    xhr.send();
  }

  //Show the link + Store the text in localStorage
  function localStore() {
    document.querySelector('#local_alert').style.display = 'block';
    var userText = document.querySelector('textArea').value;
    localStorage.setItem("myAwesomeTextEditor", userText);
  }

  //provide a link to download a file with txt content
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  function clickSave(e) {
    var userText = document.querySelector('textArea').value;
    var blob = new Blob([userText], {type: 'plain/text'});
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = "myAwesomeTextEditor" + (new Date).getTime() + '.txt';
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    }

  setInterval(saveData, 3000);
```

```css
#local_alert {
  display: none;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #AAA;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="local_alert">You're actually offline, please beware your draft is not saved on our server
  <button onclick="clickSave()">Save Now</button>
</div>

<textarea></textarea>
```

Ps: If your user leaves the page without connection, you'll be able to get the text back via `localStorage.getItem("myAwesomeTextEditor")`

PPs: A more "live" example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQfjWqHeUIFaM3Y2zbNo?p=preview) (it won't save to server but you've got the rest of the logic working). Try to disconnect , then reconnect.

Comment: _Intended_ application of `userUniqueId` ?

Comment: no, it  doesn't, it throws a security error, which is a good news actually. You will also need to change the url, and set the post data (I was assuming you always do that last)

Comment: I was thinking the browser will ask for a name for the file, and save by OS file system, but I it seams localStorage is a browser's virtual HD, right? If true, we must consider how persistent is the data:  can I turn off the PC, turn on later and recover my job? If yes, problem solved, otherwise, we need to talk to OS or user will become upset! A solution only for FF is not a problem in this case, it's an administrator, the user will use de browser selected for.

Comment: Well this solution does provide both : a "popup" will appear at top of the page to alert the user that he became offline, with a lbutton allowing him to store data in a local txt file, with name set automatically btw, and it also stores it in local storage, which may not be consistent in case  of cache cleaning. But if user don't manually clears it, it will stay on desktop (mobile browser are more unsatble as they store it in application cache). Therefore, this solution keep looking for connection and saves it back to server if user get reconnected to it.

Comment: It works! Only for FireFox, but it's good enough for me. Other browsers I may alert the user that the data is in the cache - do not clear it! Thanks, I do think this post got valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var saveNow = document.getElementById("save");

function saveFile() {
    if (confirm("save editor text")) {
      var file = document.createElement("a");
      file.download = "saved-file-" + new Date().getTime();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        file.href = e.target.result;
        document.body.appendChild(file);
        file.click();
        document.body.removeChild(file);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([editor.value], {
        "type": "text/plain"
      }));
    }
};



saveNow.addEventListener("click", saveFile, false);
```

```html
<button id="save">save editor text</button><br />
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: yeah, that's better, but see @Touffy's comment on OP

Comment: @Kaiido _"How to save data **in local hd** with javascript?"_

Comment: yeah then?  localStorage, is local HD, accessible in your browser's data files. + look at my answer, it does provide a combination of your solution (using a variant to *download  locally a text file generated in browser*) + localStorage + server-side save

Comment: _"localStorage, is local HD"_ ? "local HD" or browser memory ? _"accessible in your browser's data files"_ ? What is _"your browser's data files"_ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775844/where-is-javascripts-localstorage-strings-stored

Comment: @Kaiido If user _not_ utilizing firefox browser ? See also http://kb.mozillazine.org/Webappsstore.sqlite "webappsstore.sqlite is a binary SQLite file and should not be edited manually."

Comment: I don't know for every browser, could be a good question to ask here. I think that mobile browsers store it in cache, so you're right it might not be on HD. Anyway those use flash drive and most of comps will soon use SSD... **So what the point here?** look at the question, not only the title. OP stated that he needs to store **offline** not necessarily on HD. Your solution does provide one way, well nice, I think it's not the better one for reasons pointed by @Touffy. Then I give mine, which I hope will fit the needs of OP.